# Will apple reject my new app-iphone sdk

Tags: ios4, appstore-approval

My one application is already for sale on apple store. That application is for men. I want to create another application with almost same logic but data (HTML files) will be different as it will be for women. The reason I want to create another app is that app name includes "girlfriend" and I want to use boyfriend in new app name as it is for women. I don't want to combine both in one application as I also want to use different 512x512 image and icons for second app. Another reason is that keywords will be different for women users. For example "girlfriend" and "wife" keywords will become "boyfriend"  and "husband". If I combine both in a single app then I will not be able to use enough keywords for both women and men users as there is a limit of 100 letters.

In my new app ,first screen and seond screen will be same. But third screen will display different data (around 72 different files).

Apple rejects app if there is a similar or duplicate app on app store. Will my app get rejected even if that similar app was created by me? Will they ask me to combine both in a single application.

Comment: Why are you asking us? ask them.

Answer (score 3):

Be like Nike and Just Do It.

--Andy

Answer (score 1):

I understand your perdicament, but this is not really a question about programming. if you want advice from apple users try asking it on http://apple.stackexchange.com

but unless you have a specific need we can help with we can only guess at what the app store will do.

submitting it is the only way to find out for sure.